# Cannot post data in the model using jQuery ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and i created a function to update the data using the jquery ajax function below. I am working on a admin page(content management system). The problem is data is not inserting/updating on the model. Hope someone help me on this.

VIEW FILE:

```
    $('.ds_tpi_save').click(function () {
        var pid = $('.mychange').val();
        var tpi = $('.datatpi').val(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/ajax_update'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'html',
            data: {id: pid, tpi: tpi},
            success: function (a) {
                if (a == 'Success') {
                    $('#editContent').modal('hide');
                    $('.mychange').val('');
                    $('.datatpi').val('');
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Controller file:

```
public function ajax_update(){
    $pid = $this->input->post('id');
    $ptpi = $this->input->post('tpi');
    $update = $this->products_model->ajax_update($pid,$ptpi);
    var_dump($update); // bool(false) Fail (to insert to database)
    echo ($update)?'Success':'Fail';
}
```

Model file:

```
function ajax_update($pid,$ptpi){
    $data = array(
        'package_includes' => $ptpi,
    );
    $this->db->where('id',$pid);
    $this->db->update('products',$data);
   // return ($this->db->affected_rows()>0)?TRUE:FALSE;
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

Header:

Request admin/ajax_update,
,Request Method:POST
,Status Code:200 OK

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: If you are not changing the value of "tpi" you will always get false as the affected_rows > 0 only if values are changed.

Comment: I didn't encounter any errors. It's just the data is not updating on the model.

Comment: I am changing the value of tpi on the modal part. The method request is ok. but the data is not updating on the model.

Comment: I think the problem is the query of the modal part?

Comment: u just echo your query.what result are you getting?.Plz add that one also